# use gocolly to get div element failed

Tags: go

i want get the price 2930.15 (follow red frame)

[image]

```golang
c.OnHTML("div[id=price]", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
        fmt.Printf("test----%+v\n",e)
        price,err := strconv.ParseFloat(e.Text,64)
        //price := e.Text
        fmt.Printf("********* price----%+v\n",price)

        if err != nil {

            fmt.Printf("parse err---%+v\n",err)

        }


    })
```

then print

```
test----&{Name:div Text:@now@ attributes:[{Namespace: Key:id Val:price} {Namespace: Key:class Val:@UD_change@}] Request:0xc00013c280 Response:0xc000354240 DOM:0xc000558180 Index:0}
********* price----0
parse err---strconv.ParseFloat: parsing "@now@": invalid syntax
```

how to do ? where i wrong?

Comment: The site might have other `div`s with `id="price"`. Another possibility is that the data is loaded dynamically, which means that if you download the html page the price isn't there yet, it is loaded after the page is ready. You might be able to check this in the Network tab of the browser console if you filter by `XHR`, then reload the page